# How to automatically add a new button each time a function is called in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am making a pure guessing card game in which every time the right card is selected a new button/card will go on the screen. I have made the addButton function but I am confused about what I have to put in it. Can anyone please guide me towards the right direction as to how I should create a new button every time the function is called.

```
let card1 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
let card2 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
var random = arc4random_uniform(101)
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    card1.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
    card1.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)
    card1.addTarget(self, action: "Card1Btn:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(card1)

    card2.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
    card2.frame = CGRectMake(500, 100, 100, 100)
    card2.addTarget(self, action: "Card2Btn:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(card2)

}

func Card1Btn(sender: UIButton!){
    if random <= 50{
        print("you won")

    }else{
        print ("you Lost")

    }

}

func Card2Btn(sender: UIButton!){
    if random >= 51{
        print("you won")
    }else{
        print("you lost")
    }

}

func addButton(){

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have code to add buttons in `viewDidLoad`, so let's make that re-usable. First we will need to make your `card1` and `card2` references variable, so that we can keep track of the new cards that we will create...

```
var card1 = nil as UIButton?
var card2 = nil as UIButton?
```

Also, because the code to add buttons will be re-usable, we don't want to repeat ourselves, so let's add some constants for the frames of card 1 and card 2...

```
let card1Frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)
let card2Frame = CGRectMake(500, 100, 100, 100)
```

And we can put add-button code (which is previously repeated in `viewDidLoad`) into its own function...

```
func addButtonWithFrame(frame: CGRect) -> UIButton
{
    let card = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
    card.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
    card.frame = frame
    card.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyVC.cardButtonPressed(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(card)
    return card
}
```

Now we have a generic way to create and add a button, let's use it in `viewDidLoad`...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    card1 = self.addButtonWithFrame(card1Frame)
    card2 = self.addButtonWithFrame(card2Frame)
}
```

And now we can re-use that same code when the button is pressed...

```
func cardButtonPressed(sender: UIButton!){
    // Decide on win or lose based on current value of 'random'
    if random <= 50{
        print("you won")
    }else{
        print("you Lost")
    }
    // Set a new value for 'random' ready for next time
    random = arc4random_uniform(101)
    // Remove old card
    sender.removeFromSuperview()
    // Generate new replacement card
    let newFrame = sender.frame
    let newCard = self.addButtonWithFrame(newFrame)
    // Keep reference to new card
    if (sender == card1){
        card1 = newCard
    }else{
        card2 = newCard
    }
}
```

Comment: This is nice if I wanted to replace the card but I want to add more cards. So in the beginning there are 2 cards, then suppose the user answers it correctly there should be 3 cards.

Comment: It should be easy to modify. My answer demonstrates how you were already adding cards programatically, it just needed a little re-structuring in order to make the code re-usable. If you want to add lots of cards you can keep track of them in an array (or if they are the only sub-views of your view then `view.subviews` already tracks them for you). The main take-away is that you should use a generic function to handle card-pressed and have it behave differently (if needed) based on the card itself (`sender`). You can use the `card.tag` property if you want to give each one a unique identity.